# Dropdownlists in GridView not respecting selections

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

On an ASP.NET page, I have a gridview which contains a dropdownlist in one of its columns.  While other columns in the gridview are databound, the dropdown list is NOT, and only contains 3 preset values "Frank", "Yes", and "No".  ("Frank" is used as an example so that I don't get false readings from my preferred blank option)

```
<asp:GridView ID="testGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code1" HeaderText="Code1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code2" HeaderText="Code2" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Like Frank?">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLikeFrank">
                    <asp:ListItem>Frank</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField ... HeaderText="File" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="cmdUpdate_Click" /></div>
```

I don't need AutoPostBack on these dropdownlists, as I only want to consider their selected values when the button cmdUpdate is clicked.

```
protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool likesFrank = false;

    string selected = "";
    DropDownList ddl = null;
    GridViewRow current = null;
    // Go through each row and check the dropdown list.
    for (int i = 0; i < testGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        current = testGrid.Rows[i];
        ...
        ddl = (DropDownList)(current.FindControl("ddlLikeFrank"));

        /* THIS FOR LOOP IS WAS USED FOR INVESTIGATING THIS ISSUE*/
        for (int j = 0; j < ddl.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if (ddl.Items[j].Selected)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }           

        selected = ddl.SelectedItem.Value;
        switch (selected)
        {
            case LIKE: // "Yes"
                likesFrank = true;
                break;
            case DONT_LIKE: // "No"
                likesFrank = false;
                break;
            default: // If nothing is selected in the drop-down list, move on.
                continue;
        } // end switch block

        /* USE THE DERIVED BOOLS HERE */
   } // end for loop on grid rows
} // end method cmdUpdateClick
```

**The problem is this:** No matter what item is selected in any of the dropdownlists, my page thinks that every single one of them is set to "Frank", i.e. the first item.  Moreover, if I put a breakpoint on the top of the for loop denoted as the "Investigation code", and then interact with the page as follows:

1. Select different dropdownlist options for different rows.
2. Click the Update button.

... my debugging code tells me that none of the items are selected!  *Not one of them!!*  I can be looking at 2 Yes's and 3 No's on the page, and my debug tools in VS2008 are telling me that *every single dropdownlist has nothing selected*.

How can this be possible?  (NOTE: I have tried this with EnableViewState set to true, and with EnableViewState not even mentioned in the page header.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a hit with this. Replace index based for with this

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   var ddlVal = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("yourId")).SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

`<< use SelectedItem.Value - I think this will solve your problem >>`

**Update:**

To update the selected index of the ddl you needto do a postback. Enable autopostback=true. But here , you have mentioned you do not want autopostback, since this isthe only workaround, so place the gridview in an updatepanel to suppress postback

Comment: Decent idea, but I've tried that in debugging and the SelectedIndex for each ddl was 0, not matter what I select.

Comment: I'm not against using autopostback, I just didn't want to hit the server every time the user makes a selection, as there could be as many as a few dozen drop down lists requiring selections at a time.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks, Amit.

Answer (score 0):

At server side

```
protected void btnSaveRankChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow grv in GridViewRankChanges.Rows)
            {
DropDownList dropDownChangeRank = (DropDownList)grv.FindControl("DropDownListRank");
   StudentInfoObject.RankID = Convert.ToInt32(dropDownChangeRank.SelectedValue);
}
}
```

in grid

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select New Rank">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRank" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

On button click

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSaveRankChanges" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="RankChanges"
                        class="accordionHeader" Height="27px" OnClick="btnSaveRankChanges_Click" OnClientClick="LoadImage()" />
```

Dropdown binds in this way

```
/// <summary>
        /// bind dropdown with rank in grid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void GridViewRankChanges_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList drdList;
            // Nested DropDownList Control reference is passed to the DrdList object. This will allow you access the properties of dropdownlist placed inside the GridView Template column.
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //bind dropdown rank
                drdList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListRank");
                drdList.DataSource = RankList.GetRankList(false);
                drdList.DataTextField = "Rank";
                drdList.DataValueField = "RankID";
                drdList.DataBind();
                drdList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));

            }
        }
```

It works for me hope it helps for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are rebinding the grid on every post back, which will reload the entire data along with dropdowns. For ex. Please check if(!page.IsPostBack) before doing databiniding of gridview.
Please let me know if this is not the issue.